# How to get "news main stream" from the main facebook site?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

How to get the general information listed on the home page?

Facebook makes a request to
https://www.facebook.com/ajax/pagelet/generic.php/LitestandMoreStoriesPagelet?
with params:

ajaxpipe
ajaxpipe_token
no_script_path
data
__user
__a 1
__dyn
__req
__rev
__adt

And although it returns a json (inside a script with conditions...) is not a clean answer.

Is there another way to get that data? I do not want to use the sdk.

Answer (score 2):

If you want the 'News feed', you'll want to use the /user/home/ API endpoint:
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.1/user/home

e.g. https://graph.facebook.com/me/home?access_token=VALID_ACCESS_TOKEN will just grab your own News Feed.

You can also filter by any of the 'filter_key' values returned from the FQL query (use the Graph API Explorer and API version 2.0):

```
SELECT filter_key, name, type, value FROM stream_filter WHERE uid = me()
```

e.g. adding the query string `filter=app_2305272732` will return a feed of things from the 'Photos' app (i.e. photos added to Facebook by your friends)